# Recommended .gitignore file for Visual Studio Xamarin project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, gitignore

Looked around I can't seem to find the recommended template *.gitignore* file for Visual Studio Xamarin project.  I looked here as well https://github.com/github/gitignore

Will the Visual Studio one be ok?

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Thx in advance.

Comment: Yeah that one will be ok.

Answer (score 15):

You can check [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io) for recommended gitignore files. [Here](https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudio%2Cxamarinstudio) is the one it generated for Visual Studio and Xamarin.

Comment: how did you generate this file?  I just tried and it recognizes only VisualStudio but the file you provided link to has both VisualStudio and XamarinStudio?  Thanks

Comment: I just wrote Visual studio in the box and also wrote Xamarin and then clicked the button, not very complicated

Comment: Thanks, got it.  Tricky part is to hit enter after each entry; otherwise, wont do it :)  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

I will use this. It will ignore unnecessary files such as Android `Resource.designer.cs` and was created by **Xamarin**.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/.gitignore